# iPhone Unlock Slider With Mootools?

Tags: iphone, mootools, slider, effect, unlock

I try to make a slider similar to the iPhone unlock Slider, that forwards to a linked site, when complete, and returns to its initial position when the slider wasn't dragged to the end.

**This is not meant to be a iPhone webapp, i just want to put this to a general website as a effect.**

So far I've tried those two tests, but i'm stuck on both.

**The first is:**

```
// First Example
var el = $('slideOne'),

// Create the new slider instance
var sliderOne = new Slider(el, el.getElement('.slider'), {
    steps: 20,  // There are 35 steps
    range: [8], // Minimum value is 8

}).set(20);
```

Problem here is that i can't fire an event on (0) not on (20) aswell, i tried onComplete but this fires the function immediatly after the page is load!?

**The second**

```
$$('.textslider').setStyle('opacity', 0.8);

    $('slider1').makeDraggable({
        snap: 0,
        container: 'slideOne',
        droppables: '.slidedrop1',

    onDrop: function(element, droppable, event){
        if (!droppable);
        else console.log(element, 'dropped on', droppable, location = 'index.php/kredite.html', event);
    },
});
```

Problem here is , that the droppable don't work as fine as i hoped, sometimes i move the the slider on the invisible droppable, which indicates if the slider is dragged to the end, and nothing happens, sometimes it works fine, i think this may be due the different position of the cursor on the slider. and i can't get it done that it is only possible to slide horizontal , since it is that drag not the slider function, so i think this won be the proper way.

**On both Tests, i didn't figured out who i could return the slider back to its initial position, with a slide Effect.**

Are there some mootools cracks around who maybe could help me with this? Thanks already for the great ideas of y'all.

Comment: Nobody got some input to this??

Comment: @Marcel -- something to note is that MooTools is a less popular framework, so I think fewer SO folks follow that tag. Also, the specificity of your request is such that it's a bit more daunting than  some questions. Anyway, I hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://demos.mootools.net/demos/mootools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        var el = $('slideOne');
        var debug = $('debug');
        var ACTIVATE_VALUE = 20;
        var mySlider = new Slider(el, el.getElement('.knob'), {
            range: [0], // Minimum value
            steps: ACTIVATE_VALUE,  // Number of steps
            onChange: function(value){
                if (value == ACTIVATE_VALUE) {
                    debug.setStyles({color:'green'});
                    // go to url after delay
                    (function(){
                        location.href='http://joecrawford.com/';
                    }).delay(500);
                } else {
                    debug.setStyles({color:'red'});
                    // if not activated, reset after 2 second delay
                    (function(){
                        value = 0;
                        mySlider.set(value);
                    }).delay(3000);
                }
                debug.set('text', value);
            }
        });
        mySlider.set(0);
    }); 
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    div.slider {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #eee;
    }
    div.slider div.knob {
        background: #000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    div#debug {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: xx-large;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Slider that resets if it does not reach the end</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideOne" class="slider">
        <div class="knob"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="debug">-</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello artlung, thanks for your comments and answer, I just passed by as i recived the mail of an answer.
Thanks a lot for your attempt, but actually, my wish was that the slider slides back, just like on the iPhone. But no worries i get help at the mooforum.net, The script is working now, more or less.

How can I mark this Question as "solved"?

Comment: You marked my answer as checked and that worked. But you can answer your own question and mark that as accepted I think. You could also edit your question and show what you ended up with.